# Receipt printer feeds paper instead of printing text

Tags: qt, printing

I am working on test application for printing in `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS` with `CUPS 1.7.2` and `Qt 5.5.1 Opensource 64bit`. I've added printer with its driver in CUPS and test page is printed ok. Now, my app consists of `QTextEdit` and `QPushButton`, whose `pressed()` signal triggers following `slot`:

```
void UeCentralWidget::ueSendTextToPrinter()
{
//    QStringList availablePrintersNames=QPrinterInfo::availablePrinterNames();

//    for(int indexPrinterName=0; indexPrinterName<availablePrintersNames.size(); indexPrinterName++)
//    {
//        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
//                 << availablePrintersNames.at(indexPrinterName);
//    }   // for
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << "Text to print: "
             << this->uePrinterTextEditor()->document()->toPlainText();

    QList<QPrinterInfo> availablePrinters=QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters();

    for(int indexPrinter=0; indexPrinter<availablePrinters.size(); indexPrinter++)
    {
//        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
//                 << availablePrinters.at(indexPrinter).makeAndModel();

        if(availablePrinters.at(indexPrinter).makeAndModel().contains("POS58"))
        {
            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                     << "Printer found";

            QPrinter printer(availablePrinters.at(indexPrinter));

            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                     << printer.pageLayout().fullRect();

            QPainter printerPainter(&printer);

            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                     << printerPainter.fontInfo().family()
                     << printerPainter.fontInfo().pixelSize()
                     << printerPainter.fontInfo().pointSize();

            if(printerPainter.begin(&printer))
            {
                printerPainter.drawText(100,
                                        100,
                                        this->uePrinterTextEditor()->document()->toPlainText());
            }

            printerPainter.end();
        }   // if
    }   // for
}
```

When this `slot` executes, **printer job** is added to **`CUPS` queue**, which means printer is found, however, printer just feeds printer and no text is printed. What am I still missing?

Comment: You don't need the printerPainter.begin(&printer) or the printerPainter.end(). Try it without those.

Comment: Wow, it works! Upgrade to answer so I can upvote! But, why it works?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `printerPainter.begin(&printer)` or the `printerPainter.end()`.

I don't know why that fixes it for you, but if I was to guess it might be because explicitly calling `printerPainter.end()` **prematurely completes the paint operation before the drawing is actually done**.